# How to join the same table twice and assign table aliases in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join, pyrocms

I'm trying to make a mail system in Codeigniter with the PyroCms.
In my mail table, I have a "recipent" row and a "sender" row which contains the user id of the sender and recipient. To retrieve usernames from the ids, I'm trying to join the table together, but it simply returns me this error:

> Error Number: 1066

> Not unique table/alias: 'default_users'

> ```
> SELECT `default_mailsystem`.*, `default_users`.`username` AS modtager, `default_users`.`username` as afsender
> FROM (`default_mailsystem`)
> LEFT JOIN `default_users` ON `default_mailsystem`.`recipent` = `default_modtager`.`id`
> LEFT JOIN `default_users` ON `default_mailsystem`.`sender` = `default_afsender`.`id`
> ORDER BY `id` DESC
> ```

> Filename: /hsphere/local/home/brightmedia/reuseable.dk/modules/mail/models/mail_m.php

> Line Number: 13

My code is as follows:

```
$this->db->select('mailsystem.*, users.username AS modtager, users.username as afsender')
    ->join('users', 'mailsystem.recipent = modtager.id', 'left')
    ->join('users', 'mailsystem.sender = afsender.id', 'left');
$this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');
return $this->db->get('mailsystem')->result();
```

The funny thing is, that if I remove the last "join" operation and leave it to only join the recipient of the mail it all works out well.

Comment: @mickmackusa As requested, now renewed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of this thread, i figured that the codeigniter call missed out the possibility to do  `AS` inside of a join, Therefor this solved the issue:

```
$sql = "
    SELECT default_mailsystem.*,
           recipent.first_name AS modtager, 
           sender.first_name AS afsender
    FROM default_mailsystem
    LEFT JOIN default_profiles AS recipent ON recipent.id = default_mailsystem.id
    LEFT JOIN default_profiles AS sender ON sender.id = default_mailsystem.id
";
return $this->db->query($sql)->result();
```

Comment: This answer is not enjoying CI's query building methods.

Answer (score 10):

This is very simple

```
$this->db->select('mailsystem.*, users.username AS modtager, users.username as afsender')
$this->db->join('users', 'mailsystem.recipent = modtager.id AND mailsystem.sender = afsender.id', 'left')
$this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');
return $this->db->get('mailsystem')->result();
```

Comment: This code-only answer changes the query logic.  This answer will be misleading researchers that want to join the same table twice to the first table.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried forcing an alias in the join function (the "AS" operator won't work in the select clause as you have it...)?

```
<?php
$this->db->select('mailsystem.*, modtager.username AS modtager_name, afsender.username as afsender_name')
    ->join('`users` `modtager`', 'mailsystem.recipent = modtager.id', 'left')
    ->join('`users` `afsender`', 'mailsystem.sender = afsender.id', 'left');

$this->db->order_by('mailsystem.id', 'DESC');

return $this->db->get('mailsystem')->result();
```

Comment: Manually adding backticks defies the feature of ActiveRecord methods providing identifier escaping for you (that will still hold up when moving to a different database).  In other words, the idea of using the query builder methods is so that you _don't_ need to manually quote parts of your query.

Answer (score 1):

Use alias like this -

```
$this->db->select('mailsystem.*, users_table_a.username AS modtager, users_table_b.username as afsender')
$this->db->join('users users_table_a', 'mailsystem.recipent = users_table_a.id', 'left');
$this->db->join('users users_table_b', 'mailsystem.sender = users_table_b.id', 'left');
$this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');
return $this->db->get('mailsystem')->result();
```

Comment: This answer is missing its explanation.  This "block of code" answer will require researchers to scroll and scrutinize the OP's code with your code.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this :

```
$this->db->select('mailsystem.*, users.username AS modtager, users.username as afsender')
$this->db->join('users', 'mailsystem.recipent = modtager.id AND mailsystem.sender = afsender.id', 'left')
$this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');
return $this->db->get('mailsystem')->result();
```

**If you are using any db prefix use this **

```
$this->db->select('mailsystem.*, users.username AS modtager, users.username as afsender')
$this->db->join('users', 'mailsystem.recipent = modtager.id AND '.$this->db->dbprefix('mailsystem').'.sender = '.$this->db->dbprefix('afsender').'.id', 'left')
$this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');
return $this->db->get('mailsystem')->result();
```

Comment: This "use this" (no explanation) answer is not joining the same table to the parent table twice -- it is joining a table to the parent table once.

Answer (score 0):

```
Its very easy to get data from single table
$this->db->select('a.*,b.fname AS cname,c.fname as uname'); 
$this->db->from('tbl_menus a'); 
$this->db->join('tbl_admin_login b', 'b.id = a.create_by', 'left'); 
$this->db->join('tbl_admin_login c', 'c.id = a.update_by', 'left'); 
$this->db->order_by('a.id', 'desc'); 
return $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: This answer makes no attempt to dignify the OP's data/values.  It looks more like this code-only answer is answering a different question that requires the same technique.

Answer (score 0):

Your can try this
Core PHP

```
SELECT `custome_module`.`id`, `custome_module`.`name`, min(l1.nmark_completed) as call_waiter, min(l2.nmark_completed) as bill, min(l3.nmark_completed) as tray, min(l4.nmark_completed) as ordera
FROM `custome_module`
LEFT JOIN `restaurant_logs` as `l1` ON `custome_module`.`id` = `l1`.`nmodule_id` AND `l1`.`ntype` = 1
LEFT JOIN `restaurant_logs` as `l2` ON `custome_module`.`id` = `l2`.`nmodule_id` AND `l2`.`ntype` = 2
LEFT JOIN `restaurant_logs` as `l3` ON `custome_module`.`id` = `l3`.`nmodule_id` AND `l3`.`ntype` = 6
LEFT JOIN `restaurant_logs` as `l4` ON `custome_module`.`id` = `l4`.`nmodule_id` AND `l4`.`ntype` = 5
WHERE `custome_module`.`nbranch_id` = '142'
GROUP BY `custome_module`.`id`
```

and also in Codeigniter

```
$this->db->select('custome_module.id, custome_module.name, min(l1.nmark_completed) as call_waiter, min(l2.nmark_completed) as bill,min(l3.nmark_completed) as tray,min(l4.nmark_completed) as ordera');
$this->db->from("custome_module");
$this->db->join('restaurant_logs as l1', 'custome_module.id = l1.nmodule_id AND l1.ntype = 1', 'left');
$this->db->join('restaurant_logs as l2', 'custome_module.id = l2.nmodule_id AND l2.ntype = 2', 'left');
$this->db->join('restaurant_logs as l3', 'custome_module.id = l3.nmodule_id AND l3.ntype = 6', 'left');
$this->db->join('restaurant_logs as l4', 'custome_module.id = l4.nmodule_id AND l4.ntype = 5', 'left');
$this->db->where('custome_module.nbranch_id', $this->data['user_session']['nid']);
$this->db->get();
```