# Active Record Not Unique Table Issue

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I keep getting

> Not unique table/alias: 'users'

When running my Active Record query...

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('faults');
$this->db->join('users','users.user_id = faults.customer_id');
$this->db->join('users','users.user_id = faults.engineer_id', 'left outer');
$this->db->where('faults.fault_id', $fault_id);
```

Which translates as (In MySQL) :

```
SELECT * FROM (`faults`) JOIN `users` ON `users`.`user_id` = `faults`.`customer_id` LEFT OUTER JOIN `users` ON `users`.`user_id` = `faults`.`engineer_id` WHERE `faults`.`fault_id` = '1'
```

I have had a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077355/mysql-php-not-unique-table-alias) but have no idea how I would convert this to my active record query?

Any help appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: look at aliasing one of the joins - you can't join the same table with the same name twice.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158390/codeigniter-mysql-join-same-table-twice

Comment: You are using `users` twice for the joins, you need add an alias for one of the joins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add alias'...

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('faults AS F0');
$this->db->join('users' AS U0, 'U0.user_id = F0.customer_id');
$this->db->join('users' AS U1, 'U1.user_id = F0.engineer_id', 'left outer');
$this->db->where('F0.fault_id', $fault_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private $_fautls_table = 'fautls';

$this->db->from('fautls as f')
$this->db->join($this->_users_table . ' AS u', 'u.user_id = f.customer_id'); 
$this->db->join($this->_users_table . ' AS uu', 'uu.users_id = f.engineering_id');
```